# what event reciever to overide for document lib when changing filename

Tags: 2007, event-handlers

I have a custom list which I have written a SPItemEventReciever for and it works.
But when I do the same for a document library it doesn't fire. Is there anything I have to do if it is a document library?

Sample code below.

```
public class OrderHandler : SPItemEventReceiver { public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) { GenerateID(properties); }

public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties) { GenerateID(properties); }

void GenerateID(SPItemEventProperties properties) { SPListItem order = properties.ListItem;

string customer = order["Customer"].ToString(); string orderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(order["OrderDate"]).ToShortDateString();

order["OrderID"] = customer + " " + orderDate; order.Update();

} }
```

Do I need to treat a list different if it's a document library?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through this list of Event Receiver Troubleshooting hints:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979520.aspx

I think you might want to disable event firing before updating a list item, though.

Comment: Thanks.If i want to rename the filename when uploading a document.Should i be looking at ItemsAdded or ItemUpdating??

Comment: ItemAdded, change the AfterProperties and disable event firing so ItemUpdating isnt called immediately after,too.